# Android - Parsing XML resource references

Tags: android, xml

I'm writing a game in Android that uses a custom XML format to describe the game levels. The level files are stored in `res/xml`. I want to be able to reference Android resources (e.g., `@string` and `@drawable`). Since I'm parsing the XML myself, I'll obviously need to do this manually. So the question is: does Android have a public API for obtaining resources this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the name of the strings/drawables in and use [Resources.getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in your code. You can access your `Resources` by using `Context.getResources()`.